# How to make a global front check in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, controller

I'm making an application for a local network and I want to check the IP address to set up some session variables. Is it possible to do this globally or am I forced to do the check in every action of every controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `before_filter` in application controller. That'll make it kinda global.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :setup_session

  private
  def setup_session
    ip = request.remote_ip
    ...
  end

end
```

Comment: That will definitely work as long as you're sure to make all your controllers inherit from ApplicationController.

Comment: Yeah, but who does otherwise? I never did :-)

Comment: Me neither! It's just worth remembering, so in the off chance that someone does, they aren't left struggling for hours trying to figure it out!